# Рисование на canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Есть код, который должен заполнять canvas квадратами разного цвета

```
Rectangle R = new Rectangle();
SolidColorBrush Col = new SolidColorBrush();
R.Width = 20;
R.Height = 20;
for (int i = 4; i < 25; i++) // Отрисовка
{
    for (int y = 2; y < 12; y++)
    {
        switch (game.Board[i, y])
        {
            case 'x': Col.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0); break;
            case 'c': Col.Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0); break;
            case 'v': Col.Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255); break;
            case 'b': Col.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0); break;
            case 'n': Col.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0); break;
            case ' ': Col.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255); break;
        }
        R.Fill = Col;
        R.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (y * 20.0));
        R.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (i * 20.0));
        canv.Children.Add(R);
    }
}
```

При выполнении появляется исключение что `R` уже добавлен на canvas. Как это исправить и как лучше реализовать эту программу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заводите каждый раз новый `R`.

```
static Dictionary<char, Color> fieldColors = new Dictionary<char, Color>()
{
    { 'x', Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0) },
    { 'c', Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0) },
    { 'v', Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255) },
    { 'b', Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0) },
    { 'n', Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0) },
    { ' ', Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255) }
};

// ...
for (int i = 4; i < 25; i++)//Отрисовка
{
    for (int y = 2; y < 12; y++)
    {
        Rectangle R = new Rectangle()
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(fieldColors[game.Board[i, y]]),
            Width = 20,
            Height = 20
        };
        R.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (y * 20.0));
        R.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (i * 20.0));
        canv.Children.Add(R);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил код.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста!